# Как сделать, чтобы отображались записи пользователя, созданные только им. DJANGO

Tags: python-3.x, django

Как сделать, чтобы отображались записи пользователя, созданные только им. У меня в проекте реализована регистрация. Как сделать, чтобы авторизованный пользователь видел, только записи, которые были созданы им.

Реализовал некоторый код, у него есть главный минус, пользователь должен сам выбрать пользователя, которой создал эту запись. Как сделать, чтобы автоматически выбирался зарегистрированный пользователь.

Извиняюсь, за плохую формулировку. Спасибо за любую помощь.

```
class Tasks(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75, verbose_name="Заголовок")
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Описание задачи")
    is_done = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Выполнено?', default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Время создания")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Время обновления")
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, verbose_name='Категория', null=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey(User,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Пользователь', null=True, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('view_task', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Задания"
        ordering = ['created']


class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True, verbose_name="Название категории")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Категории"
```

```
class ProfilePageView(ListView):
    template_name = 'main/profile.html'
    context_object_name = 'tasks'
    paginate_by = 4
    model = Tasks

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Tasks.objects.filter(is_done=False, account=self.request.user)
```

```
class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category'].empty_label = "Не выбрано"

    class Meta:
        model = Tasks
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'category', 'account']
```

Answer (score 0):

чтобы пользователь не выбирал кто создал запись уберите в форме из списка fields `account` и добавьте в функцию, создающую пользователя присвоение `request.user`.

чтобы отображались записи только конкретного пользователя нужно написать такую функцию:

```
def show_posts(request, pk): #если у твоего пользователя есть slug, то можно вместо pk использовать slug
model = Tasks.objects.filter(account_id=pk)
return render(request, твой html файл, {'model': model})
```